# How to host MySQL database in my computer for a website that is hosted in a shared hosting server

Tags: mysql, host, local

So I want to do this, host my database in my computer and use it for a website that I have in another server.

I want to do this because the shared hosting limits my database connections to 25 and sometimes I get "exceeded connections" errors. I think I have enough resources to do this.

I've tried modifying my mysql .cnf, opening ports, etc, but I can't get it to work.

I'm going to host with wamp or xampp.

Any link/tutorial/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a really bad idea, on so many levels.

Comment: Why not simply move to a host that allows more than a miserable 25 concurrent connections?

Answer (score 4):

Advice: Don't.  Just don't.  The latency between your shared hosting provider and your local machine will degrade performance, and any connectivity or reliability problems at your local machine will cause your website to go down.  If you've got good enough reliability to be able to handle the database, you should just host the whole site locally and be done with it.